# Acer aspire 3 A315-54 install windows

Tags: windows-10, acer-aspire

I just bought an Acer aspire 3 A315-54 and I do not see my SSD in diskpart or even on a live Ubuntu. I can only see EFI_SHELL as a boot option from BIOS. Dose this mean a hardware failure or why am I facing this issues?

Comment: What operating system was installed on the computer when you purchased it?  Did the seller give you a recovery USB Key?

Comment: @John the laptop only has UEFI_SHEEL and no recovery USB Key was provided.

Comment: Ask Acer for a Recovery Key for it so you can get started. Some vendors only support one operating system

Comment: @John I do not think that this is the issue as I do not see any connection with the SSD that is seen on the first page of BIOS but not on the booting option or as an drive for installation.

Comment: If you cannot see the Drive at all in the opening BIOS screen, then it may indeed have a hardware issue

Comment: @John inside BIOS Information page I can see HDD0 Model name and Serial No.; but it seems not to be accessible in any installation process or booting process. :-?